# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIngredients' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mern

I am trying to dynamically create buttons from an API request. i've added food into an object and now i am dynamically creating DOM elements with a map function. I am running into the problem where i am trying to create buttons and the onClick is resulting an issue. i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIngredients' of undefined" where getIngredients is a function i am trying to call...

What i tried : before it was not working, so i fixed a binding issue ( with arrow function). that allowed the page to dynamically create elements. now the problem i am running to : clicking the button throws an error.

constructor

```
class Prediction extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { usersFood: "", domElementsObj: [], foodTemp: [] };
  }
```

get getingredients function

```
  getIngredients = params => {

    params.map(function(x, i) {
      console.log(i);
      fetch(
        `${base}?q=${params[0]}&app_id=${YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key=${YOUR_APP_KEY}`
      )
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.json());
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

dynamically creating the dom:

````
    let predictionDOM = this.state.domElementsObj.map(function(obj, i) {
      return (
        <div>
          <li key={obj[0]}>
            <button onClick={() => this.getIngredients(obj[0])}>
              {obj[0] + " -----"}
            </button>
            <span> ---- % of accuracy : {obj[1]} --</span>
            <button> Save to favorites</button>
          </li>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>testing api</h1>
        <p>Enter in your food :</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.usersFood}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your food"
        />
        <button onClick={this.getPredictions}>Make Predictions</button>
        {predictionDOM}
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: You need to use arrow functions to preserve the context of `this`. So change it to `let predictionDOM = this.state.domElementsObj.map((obj, i) => {....`

Comment: ... also use `setState` to save fetched data in the state

Comment: @xadm hey, thanks for the advice, im a bit confused though. Where would you advise me to set the state?

Comment: @Jayce444 this fixed the issue. thank you.

Comment: getIngredients ...  .then(response => { setState( resp....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You need to use arrow functions to preserve the context of this. So change it to let predictionDOM = this.state.domElementsObj.map((obj, i) => {... "

thanks for help @ Jayce444